# Char array to be broken into 3 integer variables

Tags: c++

Char arrays:

```
char inData[] = "1,13,1"
```

or

```
char inData[] = "1,9,127"
```

How could I extract data from them into 3 integer variables. Delimiter is ",". Language C++.

Answer (score 5):

Use `sscanf`

```
int a, b, c;
if (sscanf(inData, "%d,%d,%d", &a, &b, &c) == 3)
{
   // Got all three numbers converted, go ahead and use them.
}
```

Comment: Since this is apparently a C++ question it might be better to use a C++ approach rather than a C library function.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char inData[] = "1,13,1";
    istringstream inDataStream(inData);

    int a, b, c;
    char x;
    inDataStream >> a >> x >> b >> x >> c;

    cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << endl;

    return 0;
}
```